# Filter Json data in Html datatables and Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables, django-rest-framework

I added a Datatable to a page of my Django project. This tables is supposed to show some data retrieved from a Django Rest Framework API endpoint.

Here is how a sample of the data retrieved looks like:

```
{
    "item": "Someitem",
    "Price": 120,
    "Status": "Free"
},
{
    "item": "SecondItem,
    "Price": 90,
    "Status": "Taken"
},
```

I want to filter these records so that only the ones with the `Status` set to `Free` are shown in the table, but i don't really know how to do that from Jquery.

Here is the code i use to load the table:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,             
        "ajax": "/myapi/?format=datatables",
        "columns": [

            {data: "item",
            {data: "Price"},

        ]
    });
    setInterval( function () {
    table.ajax.reload();
}, 10000 );
});
```

I tried to add an if statement to check `data.Pair` inside the Ajax call, but it gave me an `undefined`. Is there any other way to do this? Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Wouldn't it probably be a better idea if your server-side API provided a way to filter the entries? Otherwise, the [official docs on column filtering](https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedheader/examples/options/columnFiltering.html) will surely help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this this way:

1. look for the [filter](https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()) method.
   **Code**:

   `var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
       "serverSide": true,
       "ajax": "/myapi/?format=datatables",
       "columns": [
           {data: "item",
           {data: "Price"},
           {data:"Status"}
       ]
   });`

Then filter like this:

```
var filteredData = table
    .column( 2 )
    .data()
    .filter( function ( value, index ) {
        return value == "Free";
    } );
```

2. You could ajax to the api and attach the filtered response to your datatable constructor (however since you use serverside I assume you are paginating from server side so you will need to change the following code to work with that)

**Code:**

`$.ajax({
        url: "/myapi/?format=datatables",
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    })
    .done((response)=>{
     if(response != undefined){
      let data = response.data, 
          filtered_data = [];
      $.each(data,function(index,value){
       if(value.Status == "Free"){
         filtered_data.push({
               "item": "Someitem",
               "Price": 120
        });
         }
       })//end each
      //fill the table
        var table = $('#mydb').DataTable({
        "serverSide": true,
        "data": filtered_data,
        "columns": [
            {data: "item",
            {data: "Price"}
        ]
    });
      }
     })`

**Edit:**
After doing a jsfiddle I realize that I miss the remove metthod for the first option so here is the fix:

```
 var filteredData =  table
    .rows()
    .indexes()
    .filter( function ( index, value ) {
    console.log(table.row(value).data().Status);
       return table.row(value).data().Status == "Taken"; 
    } );
table.rows( filteredData )
.remove()
.draw();
```

The [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eo4wgj61/98/)

Hope it helps =)

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer! Just one thing: the second snippet of code (var filterdata ... ) on which part of the jquery function should go?

Comment: You assing it in the same let clause with data.

Comment: Ok! Tried this, but the table is showing blank. Trying to understand why.

Comment: @Jack022 I made an edit to the answer also I add a jsfiddle hope it helps